# Dropping rows that fall below a certain percentage threshold of the total rows/sum [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I am having an issue with filtering out the crimes - "OffenseDescription" - that fall below 5% (the specific or general solution would help so I can reproduce/adjust requirements as needed) of the total rows in the dataframe.

This is what I've tried so far, but it is crashing the kernel and is essentially running an infinite loop/execution.

I'm also doing this in VS Code, via a Jupyter Notebook.

This is the code I've attempted so far:

```
  tot=crime.OffenseDescription.sum()  #Find sum of column 
  
  crime[crime.groupby(['OffenseDescriptiom']).transform(lambda x:
  (x.div(tot)*100)<0.05)]   #calculate percentage filter as per
  condition
```

Link to a screenshot of .head() of the dataframe I am using:

[image]

TIA

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question and what you try, (your code) ?

Comment: Just added my attempt, I forgot to initially.

Comment: Why do you use `groupby` ? Do you need test values per groups? If yes, what columns are used for grouping?

Comment: The column I am pulling the values from to set the percentage threshold is "OffenseDescription". I used groupby to group the difference Offenses together. That was my intention, anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with normalize for percentages and for remove groups bellow `0.05` filter mapped column greater or equal `0.05` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
percentage = crime.OffenseDescription.value_counts(normalize=True) 

crime[crime['OffenseDescriptiom'].map(percentage) >= 0.05)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll test the code and then close this.

Comment: Is there a way I can close the quetsion/mark it as solved, but without deleting it so that I can reference it later?